# How to create a Spring MVC project in IntelliJIdea 2019.1?

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, model-view-controller

When I create a Spring MVC project in IntelliJIdea 2019.1, There is no sub-checkbox *Spring MVC* in spring checkbox.

[image: Creating a Spring MVC project in the latest IntelliJIdea]

Comment: Could you please let the image be displayed? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tested how your project has been created with just Spring checkbox marked? I mean, Spring MVC almost always appears in Spring projects, so It maybe is already added. Take a look at you config files (pom.xml or gradle.build) for something like this:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc/5.1.6.RELEASE

I would recommend you to use this page for creating a Spring project:
https://start.spring.io/

Or instead, use Spring Tools 4: https://spring.io/tools

Both are official released by Pivotal and make some configurations for you in your pom.xml, if using Maven, or in your gradle.build, if using Gradle. Also, both provide the basic project structure.

If you further want to add some dependency, you can go to the repository (most times Maven repository, even if dealing with Gradle project) and then add to your pom.xml or gradle.build file. This one works for me 90% of the times: https://mvnrepository.com/

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure the corresponding [Spring MVC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBh9Z.png) plug-in is [enabled](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/enabling-and-disabling-plugins.html).

You should get [this option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LREE5.png) after enabling the plug-in and restarting the IDE.

Note that it's a legacy way of creating Spring projects in IntelliJ IDEA and it will use rather old Spring version, it's recommended to use the [**Spring Initializr**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jUhAZ.png) instead. [Web dependency](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3W0jl.png) is for MVC projects.

Comment: I got it. My Spring MVC plug-in is disabled. Thank you!